# How can I prevent drinking water from freezing in cold weather?

Tags: water, freezing

I'd like to keep a container of potable water in my car for when I get stuck, but in the winter it gets cold enough for bottled water to freeze.

I can't put salt in it, because then it won't be drinkable anymore (or at least, will make my condition worse if I do drink it), and I can't mix it with alcohol in case I get the car unstuck and have to drive.

What else could be added to water to sufficiently lower its freezing point without making it undrinkable?

(Or to keep it in line with physics rather than chemistry, how do I calculate the amount of pressure the water need to be under to prevent it from freezing at a given temperature, say 15-20<sup>o</sup> F?)

Comment: What about juice instead of water? Grape juice would be a good choice http://books.google.com.mx/books?id=YeF14yGITcoC&pg=PA109&dq=juice+water+freezing+point&hl=en&ei=5_sfTaGIFIyt8AaJhcTUBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CDQQ6AEwBDgK#v=onepage&q=juice%20water%20freezing%20point&f=false.

Comment: Hmm... this seems like a chemistry question to me (and therefore quite possibly off-topic for this site). Thoughts from anyone else?

Comment: @David: Uhm, melting point, freezing point have to do with physics, right? Particularly, thermodynamics.

Comment: Okay, but everything has to do with physics. Is there a survival.SE? :)

Comment: @Robert: sometimes, but if you're talking about altering the melting/freezing point by changing the composition of the solution, I would classify that under chemistry. (If the question were about altering the melting/freezing point by changing the _pressure_, that would definitely be thermodynamics.)

Comment: Besides, we are expected to know what kind of a solute will not deny the water toxic or otherwise harmful. You should either find someone with adequate knowledge in antifreezes that are not harmful to human health, or as someone above has stated carry a bottle of juice with you(keep that bottle in a cool place though)

Comment: Chemistry is just an applied physics -- I think it should stay.

Comment: Everything is applied physics with such a point of view. If there is a physicist here who has detailed knowledge about solutions and antifreezes then yes, he might get an answer. But it is more likely to find such a person in a chemistry related forum/messageboard.

Comment: @David: Fair enough, even though Non-equilibrium thermodynamics is considered physics but deals at some point with concepts of chemistry (chemical potential, for example).

Comment: @mbq: under that viewpoint we should accept any question about chemistry at all, which I don't think is right. Hopefully you agree that a question like "Is there a catalyst for the reaction $\mathrm{N}_2 + 3\mathrm{H}_2 \to 2 \mathrm{NH}_3$?" would be off topic for this site. (Perhaps we should continue this discussion in the moderator chat room so as not to clutter up the comments.)

Comment: What can you add to keep it from freezing? A duck? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may not be the answer you are looking for but I recommend you get a thermos or a well insulated flask. These are what mountaineers use and you do not have to change the chemical composition of water this way.